# can I 'combine' categories as a menu item?

Tags: categories, link-category

I have custom post type and I want to have a menu where I combine category or categories from default Wordpress post type and from my custom post type.

Let's say I have these categories

- sport, books, movies, any in default post type
- sport, books, school, any in my custom post type

can I have a menu link where I would display

- **sport** posts from both post types?
- **sport, books** posts from default post type and **any** from my custom post type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest in this situation is that you create a "CUSTOM QUERY" to query the posts.  Set this custom query into a page, then use Appearance > Menu's to add the page into your menu structure.

I hope this helps.

Comment: how do I link custom query with the page?

Comment: Just us query_posts or wp_query search them on the codex mate.